# How to force nginx to use certain URI under / path

Tags: php, nginx, uri

I have a project which is a code base for all domains, e.g. domainA.com, domainB.com and domainC.com.

In localhost I can access them by:

```
http://localhost/domainA (homepage of domainA)
http://localhost/domainA/about
http://localhost/domainA/work

http://localhost/domainB (homepage of domainB)
http://localhost/domainB/hello
http://localhost/domainB/goodbye

http://localhost/domainC (homepage of domainC)
http://localhost/domainC/foo
http://localhost/domainC/bar
```

Now, how can I create nginx configuration for those domain that instead of falling into / root path, it will fall into specific URI, so:

```
http://domainA.com (equivalent to http://localhost/domainA)
http://domainC.com/foo (equivalent to http://localhost/domainC/foo)
```

and so on...

Here's the current configuration of domainA.com but to access the content of domainA I have to type http://domainA.com/domainA (homepage of domainA).

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domainA.com;
root /var/www/html/codebaseofalldomains/public;

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/domainA_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/domainA_access.log;
}
```

How can I make this work?